# -[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, image-processing

I am using code for giving different effects to image like contrast, hue, saturation etc; and used apple `glImageProcessing` code, i jump from my view to `glimgeProcessing`, and save resultant image to property of `uiimage` in `appDelegate` file. After returning from Eagle view i used `viewDidAppear` function to change my image view to updated image

```
"-[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance"
```

my code is

```
NSLog(@"app imafe is %@",app.image);

[imageView setImage:app.image];
```

my log response is

```
2013-07-26 13:39:37.293 imageProcessingApp[1019:11303] app imafe is <UIImage: 0x73c4100>
2013-07-26 13:39:39.482 imageProcessingApp[1019:11303] app imafe is <UIImage: 0x90e0420>
2013-07-26 13:39:39.483 imageProcessingApp[1019:11303] *** -[Not A Type _cfTypeID]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x90e0b60
```

problem when try to set image to my `imageView`.

Help please

Comment: You have a memory management issue. You should search for zombies mode and the zombies instrument in Instruments. Essentially you have a dangling pointer or an object has been released too many times.

Comment: definitely its memory management, but problem is how to get which variable create this problem. And i enabled zombie objects, now what to do more

Answer (score 1):

Look like what you release `app.image` or somewhere. May be you have extra

```
CGImageRelease(app.image.CGImage);
```

or

```
[app.image release]
```

Note, what you don't need release image after `ALAsset.fullResolutionImage` and `fullScreenImage` method